# Oracle APEX - using placeholder in the text

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

On my page I display some text from the database table, the text contains placeholders that I need to replace with some page items.

Example:

Text from database

```
"My text to be displayed {0}th on the {1}th page"
```

Should become:

```
"My text to be displayed " ||:P3_COUNT||"th on the "||:P3_PAGE_NO||"th page"
```

Is that possible in Oracle APEX? How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In source:

**Type:** SQL Query (return single value)

**SQL Query:** select replace(replace(your_column, '{0}', :P3_COUNT), '{1}', 
                :P3_PAGE_NO) as your_column from your_table

Comment: sounds like just what I need. let me try it